# Using Cytoscape chart in Vue 2 component - how do I initialize chart only when container has rendered?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, cytoscape.js

I hope I can explain this without typing out a bunch of code, as I don't have the code to hand right now.

I have created a Vue component that is supposed to render a Cytoscape chart (but I imagine the same problem would occurr with any charting or mapping library). The component uses v-if to render only if it has data to render, so the component is not built on the page until it is handed data.

The component uses the 'mounted' lifecycle hook to initialize the chart once the component is rendered. However, it behaves as if the container has a size of 0x0 and clusters all of the data in the top-left corner. This seems to occur regardless of whether I specify in CSS the dimensions of the container and even if I try to explicitly set the container dimensions using Javascript just before the chart initializes.

Is there an event or hook that I can hook into in Vue 2 that will hold off on intializing the chart until the HTML content of the template is built and therefore has acessible properties, as it seems like "mounted" does not do this?

Comment: Does the cytoscape canvas not render properly, or do the nodes/edges not get placed right?

Comment: @TomAerts good question and you helped me find the solution. I assumed that the canvas was not rendering properly as I had similar problems with mapping libraries before. Actually, it was because I was dynamically adding data to the chart after intialisation, which apparently does not retrospectively apply the chart layout to new data.